# HQL language how to join query two tables like in code

Tags: java, sql, hql

I have three tables:

Manager

CompanyManager

Company

*one to many*

I need to get managers without company, in java code I can explain:

```
List<Long> managersWithCompany = (List<Long>) session.createQuery("Select distinct mc.idManager from ManagersCompany mc").list();
List<Long> allManagers = (List<Long>) session.createQuery("select m.id from Manager m").
```

//for example in managersWithCompany we have ids: 2 3 4 

//for example in allManagers we have ids: 1 2 3 4 5 

so, how to create query, that will give to me 1 5? 

 again, i need managers that HAVE NOT company

 its code on java, i need only query without code, somebody know?

```
        ArrayList<Long> answer = new ArrayList<>();
        allManagers.forEach(actMan -> {
        boolean add = true;
        for (Long allManager : managersWithCompany ) {
              if (actMan.equals(allManager)) {
                  add = false;
                 break;
             }
           }
           if (add) answer.add(actMan);
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using SQL:

```
select m.id
from Manager m
where not exists (SELECT * FROM ManagersCompany mc
                  WHERE m.id = mc.idManager)
```

Comment: You are the best! 
Exactly!
Thanks, man!
will accept your answer in 10 minutes